# PPA for Adobe Brackets in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ppa, adobe, official-repositories, adobe-brackets

Is there any official PPA for Adobe Brackets in Ubuntu 16.04 ? I currently download .deb files from their website and install it manually. I want to automate the updating processing like Atom.

Comment: No official PPA available ? I am a bit vary of using unofficial ones. Thanks.

Comment: @user227495 with the amount of trust you can give webupd8, it might as well be official. The source is very reputable, so there's not much need for worry.

Comment: @user227495: "Official PPA" is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a PPA by Webupd8 team.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

`Webupd8` offers many PPAs. You can get PPA for  `atom` and `sublime` also from [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team)

Comment: Is that PPA a trusted one ? Thanks.

Comment: That seems to be the only one @user227495 Web Update is a trusted source.